# TUSafariActivity code sign failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

Good afternoon, everyone

Recently I upgrading my Mac OS to 10.12.2 Beta and Xcode ( version 8.2 beta 8C23 ), also update the pods package.

[image]

However, after upgrading these, my project fail to build ( even for simulator ) and it seems one of my Pods packages, TUSafariActivity,  fail to build. the error message is like this...

[image]
Does this mean it is the TUSafariActivity's problem? if yes, Should I wait for their fix??

Thank you for advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

It turns out my pod version is too old. after update pod version then update pod, the problem is solved.